# Google Batch Translate Documents - Processing Progress

Tags: batch-processing, google-translate

I've followed the instructions on the [Google Translate Multiple Documents](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/translate-documents#translate_documents_batch) guide, set up a batch of Office documents to be translated and successfully submitted a request using Powershell. I get the expected response as follows, apparently indicating that the request is successful:-

```
{
  "name": "projects/<My-Project-Number-Here>/locations/us-central1/operations/20220525-16311653521501-<Generated-Job-ID-GUID>",
  "metadata": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.translation.v3.BatchTranslateDocumentMetadata",
    "state": "RUNNING"
  }
}
```

All good so far.

However, the problem is that I dont see any translated documents appearing in the Storage Bucket that I specified in the output_config of the request .JSON file, and I can't seem to find a way to view the status of the long-running job that it has created.

If I re-submit the same job, it tells me that the output bucket is in-use by another batch process, which indicates that something is happening.

But, for the life of me, I can't see where in the Google Cloud Dashboard or via the gcloud command line, to query the status of the job it has created. It just says that it has created a batch a job and that's it. No further feedback. I am assuming that it fails somehow as there are no resulting translated files in the output storage bucket location.

Does anyone have experience with this and could they share how to query the job?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Glenn

EDIT: OK - the job hasn't failed - I just needed to be patient as I checked the output storage bucket and there are a bunch of files in there, so it is working (phew - I have a lot of documents to translate). But I would still like to know if there is a way to see the status of the job.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find the staus of job?

Comment: I didn’t need to get the status of the job in the end, so never resolved my original question. It was merely a matter of adjusting my expectations to match the speed at which Google Translate was working. Not a very useful answer though - apologies for that.

Comment: I was trying to use NodeJs client library and it was able to give some error message. Hope this will be helpful to anyone who has the same doubt in the future